# How to preview a cms page in Magento 2 admin panel

Tags: magento2, cms-pages, page-builder

Is it possible to preview the CMS page before push live?

I can't preview my page while creating a page on cms page in admin panel Magento 2.
How can I preview?

Comment: "View" link should be already there which shows the preview of CMS page from CMS pages grid.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora But the issue is View option is available after publishing the cms page, as it requires to save.. and after saving the page it gets publish and i am only able to preview it after publishing it.

Comment: Nice feature (y). I have bookmarked your question.

Comment: Are you going to create a pull request for this feature  I am waiting :D

Comment: If it gets done, I will be interested to pull. :) BTW you can have a look at https://marketplace.magento.com/mageside-admin-useful-links.html

Comment: @MohitKumarArora but this extension doesn't provide a preview before publishing the page.

Comment: Are you using Page Builder?

Comment: @brentwpeterson yes

Answer (score 1):

You can update and preview changes using the schedule update

You can see that you can schedule your update, in this you get to update your content without going live, you can save and preview

[image]

[image]